# Error on running django server: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_forms_bootstrap'

Tags: django, forms, server

On trying to run the server for the following project https://github.com/hschafer2017/django-MultiUsers, I get this error:

```
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_forms_bootstrap'
```

I have installed **requirements.txt** and also tried:

**pip install bootstrap3**
and
**pip install django-bootstrap-form**
as well as 
**django-bootstrap-forms==0.1**

but the same error occurs.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I could resolve this problem and run the server without any errors?

**Additional note:** pip install django-bootstrap-forms==3.1.0 (referring to requirements.txt),I got the following error, which could have something to do with the problem?

```
Collecting django-bootstrap-forms==3.1.0
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-bootstrap-forms==3.1.0 (from versions: 0.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for django-bootstrap-forms==3.1.0
```

Comment: Because the package is called `django-forms-bootstrap`, not `django-bootstrap-forms`. But if you did `pip install -r requirements.txt` it would install everything in that file anyway,

Comment: Yes,and that is what was throwing me. I had already installed requirements, but it hadn't seemed to work

Answer (score 1):

Tried this:

```
pip install django_forms_bootstrap
```

.... which did work! 
Simple, but will leave in in case anyone else searches with the same error.